# XPages field validation and Parsley

Tags: validation, xpages

I have never been able to get the standard field validation to work particularly well and have tried several different options where I have done the validation in the onClick event of the Save button. 
For a number of reasons I need to do the actual save in the button then do a redirect. I have tried using a "Submit" button with the Save = false but that has created a number of other issues. 
So in my Save button I would like to issue a page Validate action but can't figure out how to do that.

Secondly I have looked at the Parsley validation and like what I see there but not sure how one would integrate it into XPages? Can some one point me to some examples?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like two questions in one? A question on server side validation and then a question on how to use Parsley for client side validation.

Comment: Probably right, would settle for how to integrate Parsley! Are there any examples on how to use it in XPages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code snippet by Don Mottolo: http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=ssjs-form-validation-that-triggers-errormessage-controls

You can use it to put your validation into a script library but you will still be able to use the "Display Error" controls.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks like that will do the job nicely. Will take a bit of work to get it working but it looks like it will. Thanks.